# OrientDb Class already exists in current database when createing a new Class

Tags: rest, orientdb, graph-databases

Using the orientdb restful api to create classes always returns an error message

```
{
  "errors": [
{
  "code": 500,
  "reason": 500,
  "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Class 'testclass' already exists in current database name=\"test\""
}
  ] 
}
```

It doesnt matter what the class name is, it always returns that error, but creates the class anyway.

I post as http://user:pass@localhost/command/test/sql/CREATE CLASS testclass EXTENDS V

Any ideas?

I would prefer to use the create class endpoint in the api, but I cant find anywhere in the docs how to specify the abstraction when you create the class

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I tried you case and it works for me, I used Postman and OrientDB version 2.2.27 and as you can see from my screen the class is correctly created:

[image]

I get your same error only if I run the same command twice, and it's correct obtain that error because the class was created previously so, it's already exists.

Hope it helps

Regards